# Chamar arquivo.html a partir de uma função

Tags: javascript, html5

O mais comum é que links para outros arquivos html sejam feitos através da tag `<a href>`, porém, como eu faria para chamar um arquivo.html de dentro de uma função javascript? Ou seja, o usuário clica no link cujo evento **onclick** está apontando para uma função qualquer e dentro dessa função eu faria a chamada para o arquivo .html.

O comum é que façamos `<a href="anyhtmlfile.html">Clickme</a>`

Comment: Qual seria o beneficio para tal método?

Answer (score 1):

Basta utilizar window.location para realizar o redirecionamento.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="redirecionar()">Clickme</a>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function redirecionar() {
                window.location = 'http://google.com.br';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```